# Grep with option -P in busybox

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

I want to run a grep command with option `-P` in a  BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary inside a kubernetes pod with the image `curlimages/curl:7.75.0`

```
curl -s -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones?name=$CFZONE_NAME"\
-H "X-Auth-Email: $CFUSER"\ 
-H "X-Auth-Key: $CFKEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
| grep -Po '(?<="id":")[^"]*' \ # <- This is the culprit 
| head -1 
    
curl -s -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$CFZONE_ID/dns_records?Name=$CFRECORD_NAME" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: $CFUSER" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: $CFKEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"\
| grep -Po '(?<="id":")[^"]*'\ # <- This is the culprit
| head -1
```

unfortunately the `-P` is not available

```
grep: unrecognized option: P
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.


  Usage: grep [-HhnlLoqvsriwFE] [-m N] [-A/B/C N] PATTERN/-e PATTERN.../-f FILE [FILE]...

Search for PATTERN in FILEs (or stdin)

        -H      Add 'filename:' prefix
        -h      Do not add 'filename:' prefix
        -n      Add 'line_no:' prefix
        -l      Show only names of files that match
        -L      Show only names of files that don't match
        -c      Show only count of matching lines
[...]
```

How can workaround this?

Comment: Is Perl installed on the busybox?

Comment: I am using `curlimages/curl:7.75.0` from [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated). I think it is not installed

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `grep` with `cut`?

```
grep -o '"id":"[^"]*' | cut -f4- -d\"
```

Comment: Hmm somehow that did not work. I decided to create my own dockerImage.

Comment: What do you mean by "somehow"?

Comment: The command is stuck when executing. I cannot look into the pod. while runnig